# Error con ruta de archivos en PHP

Tags: php, url, redirección

Estoy teniendo un error de rutas pero solo sucede cuando redirecciono con una url amigable.

Ejemplo

Directorio

```
facturaciones
    |_ modulos
    |    |_ pdf
    |        |_vendor
    |
    |_ phpfiles
    |    |_ invoice.php
    |    |_ default.php
    |
    |
    |_ index.php
```

default.php

```
<a href="./page=invoice&idfactura=<?=$row['idfactura'];?>">Ver Factura</a>

// resultado: http://localhost/poyo/facturaciones/?page=invoice&@=116
```

invoice.php

```
$data = $admin->generafactura($_GET['idfactura']);
   
// PDF SDK
require __DIR__.'/../modulos/pdf/vendor/autoload.php';
```

En `invoice.php` llamo al SDK para crear una factura en un archivo PDF. El problema es que en el archivo `invoice.php` se ve vacío y no puedo resolverlo, ya vi varias preguntas relacionadas, aplique lo entendido y no logro avanzar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda!

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿A qué PDF te refieres? ¿Dónde es el problema, en `default.php` o en `invoice.php`? ¿Esto qué es o qué debería ser `http://localhost/poyo/facturaciones/?page=invoice&@=116`?

Comment: Ahí edite el problema... lo que hago es llamar al modulo `pdf` para generar una factura en un `.pdf`, se entinde?

Comment: *El problema es que en el archivo invoice.php se ve vacío* ¿Qué se ve vacío en el archivo `invoice.php`?

Comment: No dentro del archivo, sino cuando quiero ver los datos... el frontend. Ahí deje una imagen

Comment: Tratas de decir que al hacer click en el enlase `Ver Factura` te redirige a ella pero no puedes ver sus datos? osea que no puedes ver el contenido de la factura?

Comment: Claro, no me muestra nada...

Comment: Si le das a click derecho copiar enlace ¿qué enlace se produce exactamente? Debes verificar que se produce la ruta correcta y que el archivo PDF existe. O, si eso hace una llamada a un archivo que genera el PDF de forma dinámica debes explicarlo... todo eso no queda claro en la pregunta. Para encontrar con mayor exactitud y rapidez el problema convendría que revises en log de errores en el servidor.